# How to makereact-native render component on state change when mqtt client state changes in background in different navigation component?

Tags: node.js, react-native, react-hooks, mqtt

I am making mqtt control app and I need to real-time rerender connected/not connected indication in react navigation tabs when mqtt client changes connection status. Mqtt client calls some callback functions when connection state changes, these functions contain useState hook that changes isConnected boolean indicator. But this useState is defined in different screen than tabs navigator. How can I real-time rerender tabs when they are opened and connection state change occurs?

here is app.tsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect  } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Alert, Settings } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {HomeScreen, DeviceTabs, mqtt} from './components';
import {SafeAreaProvider} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { mqttDevices, mqttCommands, mqttTopics } from './components';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'; // Import AsyncStorage

import {MqttClient} from './utils/MqttClient';

const backgroundImage = require('./assets/login_background.png'); // Replace with the path to your image


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('Test');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('Test');
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [configured, setConfigured] = useState(false);
  const [brokerAddress, setBrokerAddress] = React.useState(String(mqtt.brokerAddress));
  const [webSocketPort, setWebSocketPort] = React.useState(mqtt.webSocketPort);
  const [clinetId, setClientId] = React.useState(String(mqtt.options.clientId));

  const authenticate = () => {
    if (username === 'Test' && password === 'Test') {
      setAuthenticated(true);
    } else {
      Alert.alert('Invalid credentials. Please try again.');
    }
  };

  const setMqttParamters = () => {
    mqtt.setBrokerAddress(brokerAddress);
    mqtt.setClientId(clinetId);
    mqtt.setWebSocketPort(Number(webSocketPort));
    setConfigured(true);
  };
// ----- create mqttTopics list from mqttDevices list
useEffect (() =>{
  mqttTopics.clear();
  for(const keys in mqttDevices){
    mqttTopics.set(keys, {pub: "smartrfurniture/" + keys + "/command", sub: "smartrfurniture/" + keys + "/response"});
    console.log(mqttDevices[keys]);
  }
  mqttTopics.set("ping", {pub: "smartfurniture/ping", sub: "smartfurniture/pingresponse"});
},[]);

// ------------------------------------------------------

  if (!authenticated) {
    return (
      <ImageBackground source={backgroundImage} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Username"
            value={username}
            onChangeText={(text) => setUsername(text)}
            style={styles.input}
          />
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Password"
            secureTextEntry
            value={password}
            onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
            style={styles.input}
          />
          <Button title="Login" onPress={authenticate} />
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }

  if (!configured) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="MQTT Broker Address"
          value={brokerAddress}
          onChangeText={(text) => setBrokerAddress(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="WebSocket Port"
          value={String(webSocketPort)}
          onChangeText={(text) => setWebSocketPort(Number(text))}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Client ID"
          value={clinetId}
          onChangeText={(text) => setClientId(text)}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <Button title="OK" onPress={setMqttParamters} />
      </View>
    );
  }
 
  const client = new MqttClient(mqtt.brokerAddress, mqtt.webSocketPort, mqtt.options.clientId);
  exports.client = client;

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="HomeScreen"
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{title: 'Homescreen'}}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Devices"
            component={DeviceTabs}
            options={{title: 'Devices'}}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
...
```

Homescreen.js where the client callback functions with mqttConnected indicator useState are defined:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';



export function HomeScreen({ navigation}) {
  const [mqttConnected, setMqttConnected] = React.useState('');
  const app=require("../App");
  const client = app.client;
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    client.onConnect(onSuccess, onConnectionLost);
  }, []);


  const onSuccess = () => {
    console.info('Mqtt Connected');
    setMqttConnected(true);
  };

  const onConnectionLost = () => {
    setMqttConnected(false);
    console.info('Mqtt Disconnected');
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.statusContainer}>
        <Text
          style={{
            color: '#fff',
            fontWeight: '600',
          }}>
          {mqttConnected ? 'MQTT connected' : 'Not connected'}
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <Text
          style={{
            color: '#888',
            fontWeight: '600',
            fontSize: 30,
            paddingHorizontal: 10, 
          }}>
          Welcome
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Devices", {mqttConnected})} title="Devices"></Button>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
...
```

DeviceTabs.js where I want to show connection indicator according to mqttConnected in real time. For convenience I left only one tab function CabinetScreen() with indicator.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Image, Switch, Button} from 'react-native';
import Slider from '@react-native-community/slider';
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {mqttDevices, mqttCommands, mqttTopics} from './';
//import {onSubscribeTabletopResponse, onSubscribeCabinet} from './';
//import {onSubscribeCabinet, onPublishHandler} from './';

export function DeviceTabs({ route }) {
  const {mqttConnected} = route.params;
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
  const flatbackgroundImage = require('../assets/flatbackground.png'); // Replace with the path to your image
  
  var app=require("../App");
  const client = app.client;

function CabinetScreen() {
    return (
      <View style={{height: '100%'}}>
        <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
          <View style={styles.statusContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.statusText}>
              {mqttConnected? 'MQTT connected' : 'Not connected'}
            </Text>
          </View> 
          <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.tabTitleStyle}>Cabinet Page</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button 
            onPress={() => onPublishHandler(mqttTopics.get('cabinet').pub, mqttCommands.get('open'))} 
            title='Open'/>
          <View style={styles.spaceVertical} />
          <Button 
            onPress={() => onPublishHandler(mqttTopics.get('cabinet').pub, mqttCommands.get('close'))} 
            title='Close'/>
          <View style={styles.spaceVertical} /> 
          <Button 
            onPress={() => onPublishHandler(mqttTopics.get('cabinet').pub, mqttCommands.get('stopall'))} 
            title='Stop'/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.messageContainer}>
          <View style={styles.messageTitle}>
            <Text style = {styles.messageTitleStyle}>Cabinet response message:</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.messageField}>
            <Text style = {styles.messageText}>{responseCabinet}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }


  function activateDevice(device){
    pubTopic = lastActivated;
    if (pubTopic!='nothing') onPublishHandler(pubTopic, mqttCommands.get('deactivate'));
    pubTopic = 'smartfurniture/'+device+'/command';
    setLastActivated(pubTopic);
    onPublishHandler(pubTopic, mqttCommands.get('activate'));
  }

  return (
    
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: 'blue',
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        tabBarShowLabel: true,
        tabBarStyle: [{ display: 'flex' }, null],
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Bed"
        component={BedScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Bed',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Image
              source={require('../assets/bed_icon.png')}
              style={{ width: 24, height: 24, resizeMode: 'contain', tintColor: color }}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="Cabinet" component={CabinetScreen} listeners={{tabPress:  () => {activateDevice('cabinet');}}} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Glass Cabinet" component={GlassCabinetScreen} listeners={{tabPress:  () => {activateDevice('glasscabinet');}}}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Motor Control" component={MotorScreen} listeners={{tabPress:  () => {activateDevice('cabinet');}}}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Robot" component={RobotScreen} listeners={{tabPress:  () => {activateDevice('mqtt');}}}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Tabletop" component={TabletopScreen} listeners={{tabPress:  () => {activateDevice('tabletop');}}}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Lights" component={LightScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
...
```

I know hove to pass the props between screens in navigation but it looks like they only update when the tab screen is reopened. I would like to see the connection indication rerendered at the moment the callback function is called in background. It works normally in HomeScreen.js where useState is defined. I use react-native with nodejs